# Is there a Stack Exchange site to ask for language identification?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm curious what the writing on the back of this truck says, and what language it is. Is there a proper SE site where I can post that as a question?

[image]

Comment: I think it is a dialect of bangla.

Comment: Try to draw them into Google Translate and see...?

Comment: It is written in __Punjabi__ language. On the left side, it means, "I have done so many sins, O God, please forgive me and let them not to expose publically". On the right side, it is the name of some company or firm: "Dhami and Bading Brothers".

Comment: @harman052 - Excellent, thank you. Ultimately, that was what I wanted to find, assuming a proper place to post the question.

Comment: Holy dogcrap I knew truckers were sketchy but jeez...

Comment: @Won't - just for clarity, how does indicate the sketchiness of truckers?

Comment: "I have done so many sins, O God, please forgive me and let them not to expose publically", on the truck... Exactly what "so many sins" has the trucker committed? And why does he want "them not to expose publically" because he'll be arrested? *What kind of sins are we talking about here???*

Comment: @Won't - interesting. Or could it be that he has a high standard/long list for himself of what constitutes a sin? Perhaps as prelude to some process of improving over time, while believing the world doesn't need to know details, because that would be embarrassing.

Comment: @Won't: Actually it is a bit old but famous song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3tGfatdJgA, indeed a beautiful song! It is written in general context, not specifically for truck drivers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Five years ago, this would have been welcome on linguistics.stackexchange.com ([relevant meta thread](//linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/465/2394)), although now it seems to be [no longer considered on topic](//linguistics.stackexchange.com/tags/language-identification). However, you could ask on their chat whether said chat would be an appropriate place to ask.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. :)

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a site that does language identification.

I was going to suggest asking in chat, but that would be effectively asking a random bunch of people to identify the language which wouldn't get you very far and could be seen as being rude (depending on where you asked it).

Is this an image you took yourself or one from the internet? If it's the latter then the site you found it on might give you some clues.

If it's the former then look for a room that advertises its locale - (e.g. C# programmers in Burma<sup>*</sup>, Travelling in Africa<sup>*</sup>) then ask there if they'd mind trying to id the language. Don't just join the room and post the picture.

<sup>*</sup> Room names made up to illustrate the point.

Comment: It's one that I took a few years back. But it's on the interwebs now.